# MySQL Update 2 tables using 2 mysql_query() in single php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

```
for(some loop condition):
mysql_query("UPDATE `details` SET
    `url_battlelog`                     = '".$stats[$out]['url_battlelog']."',
    `url_bf3stats`                      = '".$stats[$out]['url_bf3stats']."',
    `rank_img_medium`                   = '".$stats[$out]['rank_img_medium']."',
    `country_name`                      = '".$stats[$out]['country_name']."',
    `country`                           = '".$stats[$out]['country']."',
    `country_flag`                      = '".$stats[$out]['country_flag']."',
    `rank_number`                       = '".$stats[$out]['rank_number']."',
    `score_total`                       = '".$stats[$out]['score_total']."',
    `time_total`                        = '".$stats[$out]['time_total']."',
    `dogtag_basic_img`                  = '".$stats[$out]['dogtag_basic_img']."',
    `dogtag_basic`                      = '".$stats[$out]['dogtag_basic']."',
    `dogtag_advance_img`                = '".$stats[$out]['dogtag_advance_img']."',
    `dogtag_advance`                    = '".$stats[$out]['dogtag_advance']."'
WHERE `name_player` = '".$stats[$out]['name_player']."'
")
or die(mysql_error());

for(2nd loop condition):
mysql_query("UPDATE `weapons` SET
    `img`                                   = '".$gun_img."',
    `name`                                  = '".$gun_name."',
    `kit`                                   = '".$gun_kit."',
    `time`                                  = '".$gun_time."',
    `kills`                                 = '".$gun_kills."',
    `headshots`                             = '".$gun_hs."',
    `shots`                                 = '".$gun_shots."',
    `hits`                                  = '".$gun_hits."',
    `star_total`                            = '".$gun_star_c."',
    `star_img`                              = '".$gun_star_i."',
    `star_need`                             = '".$gun_star_n."',
    `rank_curr`                             = '".$gun_rank_c."',
    `rank_all`                              = '".$gun_rank_w."',
    `desc`                                  = '".$gun_desc."',
    `category`                              = '".$gun_cat."',
    `range`                                 = '".$gun_range."',
    `fire_rate`                             = '".$gun_fire_rate."',
    `ammo`                                  = '".$gun_ammo."',
    `auto_fire`                             = '".$gun_fire_auto."',
    `burst_fire`                            = '".$gun_fire_burst."',
    `single_fire`                           = '".$gun_fire_single."',
    `unlock_total`                          = '".$unlock_total."',
    `unlock_done`                           = '".$unlock_done."',
    `unlock_p`                              = '".round($unlock_p)."'
WHERE `name_player` = '".$stats[$out]['name_player']."'
")
or die(mysql_error());
```

the problem is that only 2nd table (weapons) is updating, 1st table (details) is not showing any changes. Doesn't show any error.

I have same type of script for inserting data into both tables and its working fine.

I'm new to MySQL and PHP. sorry for bad English....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you test by writing your SQL ? I think your [WHERE] condition is not fully filled

Comment: echo your SQL for updating details, then try to execute your query in your query browser,you will see what's wrong with your query

Comment: sorry.. but how to do that ?

Comment: $SQL=`"UPDATE details SET bla bla"`; echo $SQL; mysql_query($SQL);

Comment: nothing... No errors and nothing is wrong, data for both tables is same (format wise).